# How do you rotate a system of particles (a 2d matrix of size =num_particles*3) so that some entries become zero

Tags: algorithm, rotation, fortran, computational-geometry, particles

So suppose you have a system of particles given by

```
pos = [x1, y1, z1,
       x2, y2, z2,
            .
            .
       xn, yn , zn]
```

I want to rotate the system so that the first particle will move to the origin, i.e., x1 = 0 , y1 =0 , z1=0, the second particle moves to the z-axis, i.e., new coordinates x2 =0, y2 = 0, z2 = new z2, and finally the third particle moves to the yz plane, i.e., x3=0, y3 = new y3, z3 = new z3. The important thing is that the distance between all particles must preserved.

I tried to use [Givens Rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Givens_rotation) for zeroing the coordinates I specified above but this method changes the distance between particles.  I am coding in Fortran 90.

**Added:** Here is a subroutine I call it constraint. I tried by building some rotation matrices to rotate the system as I described above. As expected I get the zeros I want. But when I measure the distances between particles after calling constraint, they are not the same as before calling it (Actually what I do is I calculate the energy of the system which is invariant under translation and rotation because it only depends on particles separation)

```
SUBROUTINE constraint(pos)
REAL(KIND=dp), DIMENSION(np,3), INTENT(INOUT) :: pos
REAL(KIND=dp) :: r1, r2
REAL(KIND=dp), DIMENSION(3,3) :: rotMatrix
!------------------
! Translating the whole system so that the first particle at the origin
IF(pos(1,1) .NE. 0.0d0) THEN
    pos(:,1) = pos(:,1) - pos(1,1)
END IF  
IF(pos(1,2) .NE. 0.0d0) THEN
    pos(:,2) = pos(:,2) - pos(1,2)
END IF
IF(pos(1,3) .NE. 0.0d0) THEN
    pos(:,3) = pos(:,3) - pos(1,3)
END IF

! First rotation: Roates the whole system so that the second particle is on
! the z-axis
IF(pos(2,1) .NE. 0.0d0 .OR. pos(2,2) .NE. 0.0d0) THEN
    r1 = NORM2(pos(2,:))
    r2 = NORM2(pos(2,1:2))
    r2 = r2*r2
    rotMatrix(1,1) = ( pos(2,2)*pos(2,2) + ( pos(2,1) * pos(2,1) * pos(2,3) ) /r1 ) / r2
    rotMatrix(1,2) = pos(2,1)* pos(2,2) * (-1.0d0 + pos(2,3)/r1) / r2
    rotMatrix(1,3) = - pos(2,1) / r1
    rotMatrix(2,1) = rotMatrix(1,2)
    rotMatrix(2,2) = ( pos(2,1)*pos(2,1) + ( pos(2,2) * pos(2,2) * pos(2,3) ) /r1 ) / r2
    rotMatrix(2,3) = - pos(2,2) / r1
    rotMatrix(3,1) =  pos(2,1) / r1
    rotMatrix(3,2) =  pos(2,2) / r1
    rotMatrix(3,3) =  pos(2,3) / r1

    pos = MATMUL( pos, TRANSPOSE(rotMatrix) )
END IF

! Second rotation: Roates the whole system around the z-axis so that the 
! third particle is on the zy-plane
! the z-axis
IF( pos(3,1) .NE. 0.0d0 ) THEN
    r1 = NORM2(pos(3,1:2))

    rotMatrix(1,1) = pos(3,2) / r1
    rotMatrix(1,2) = - pos(3,1) / r1
    rotMatrix(1,3) = 0.0d0
    rotMatrix(2,1) = pos(3,1) / r1
    rotMatrix(2,2) = - pos(3,2) / r1
    rotMatrix(2,3) = 0.0d0
    rotMatrix(3,1) = 0.0d0
    rotMatrix(3,2) = 0.0d0
    rotMatrix(3,3) = 1.0d0

    pos = MATMUL( pos, TRANSPOSE(rotMatrix) )
END IF
END SUBROUTINE constraint
```

Comment: Do you have any code? Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: yes i do..I will post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I was writing the answer, you have included your code, which seems to be based on rigid-body rotation. Because my code below is also based on rigid-body rotation, I will skip detailed explanations; so please compare the two codes if necessary (FYI, in my case, I perform sequential Rz -> Ry -> Rz rotations, as defined by the Euler angles).

```
program rotation
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: N = 10, x=1, y=2, z=3
    real, parameter :: pi = acos(-1.0)
    real :: pos( 3, N ), alpha, beta, gamma, phi, ref( 3 ), rot(3,3)
    integer i

!> Initial coordinates.
    do i = 1, N
        phi = 2.0 * pi / N * (i - 1)
        pos( :, i ) = [ cos( phi ), sin( phi ), 0. ] &
                      * ( 3.0 + 2.0 * mod(i,2) ) * 0.55
    enddo
    pos(2,:) = pos(2,:) + 5.0

!> Translate the system such that pos(:,1) = 0.
    ref(:) = pos( :, 1 )
    do i = 1, N
        pos( :, i ) = pos( :, i ) - ref(:)
    enddo

!> Get the polar coordinates of pos(:, 2).
    beta  = acos( pos( z, 2 ) / norm2( pos(:, 2) ) )  !! in [0,pi]
    alpha = atan2( pos( y, 2 ), pos( x, 2 ) )         !! in [-pi,pi]

!> Apply Rz( -alpha ).
    pos = matmul( get_Rz( -alpha ), pos )

!> Apply Ry( -beta ).
    pos = matmul( get_Ry( -beta ), pos )

!> Get the azimuthal angle of pos(:, 3).
    gamma = atan2( pos( y, 3 ), pos( x, 3 ) )

!> Apply Rz( -gamma + pi/2 ).
    pos = matmul( get_Rz( -gamma + pi/2 ), pos )

!> Result.
    print *, "new coord:"
    do i = 1, N
        print "(3f10.5)", pos( :, i )
    enddo

    rot = matmul( get_Rz( -gamma + pi/2 ), &
          matmul( get_Ry( -beta ), get_Rz( -alpha ) ) )

    print *, "full rotational matrix (to be applied after translation):"
    do i = 1, 3
        print "(3f10.5)", rot( i, : )
    enddo

contains

    function get_Rz( ang ) result( R )
        real :: ang, R(3,3)
        R( 1, : ) = [ cos( ang ), -sin( ang ), 0. ]
        R( 2, : ) = [ sin( ang ),  cos( ang ), 0. ]
        R( 3, : ) = [    0.,          0.,      1. ]
    endfunction

    function get_Ry( ang ) result( R )
        real :: ang, R(3,3)
        R( 1, : ) = [  cos( ang ), 0., sin( ang ) ]
        R( 2, : ) = [    0.,       1.,    0.      ]
        R( 3, : ) = [ -sin( ang ), 0., cos( ang ) ]
    endfunction
endprogram
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

Rewriting the rotation matrices in terms of Cartesian coordinates gives

```
!> Apply Ry( -beta ) * Rz( -alpha ).
    p(:) = pos( :, 2 )
    r1 = norm2( p(:) )
    L  = norm2( p( 1:2 ) )
    Lr = L * r1

    rot( 1, : ) = [ p(z)*p(x) / Lr, p(z)*p(y) / Lr, - L / r1   ]
    rot( 2, : ) = [    - p(y) / L,       p(x) / L,     0.      ]
    rot( 3, : ) = [      p(x) / r1,      p(y) / r1, p(z) / r1  ]

    pos = matmul( rot, pos )

!> Apply Rz( -gamma + pi/2 ).
    p(:) = pos( :, 3 )
    L = norm2( p( 1:2 ) )
    rot( 1, : ) = [  p(y) / L, p(x) / L, 0. ]
    rot( 2, : ) = [ -p(x) / L, p(y) / L, 0. ]
    rot( 3, : ) = [   0.,        0.,     1. ]

    pos = matmul( rot, pos )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. It worked! I still don't see where I made the mistake in my code though.

Comment: I will also try decoding your code if you put some reference/page used for your calculations (it seems the final Rz is similar to mine, but the first rotation matrix seems complicated).

Comment: first one I used mathematica to get it using the function "RotationMatrix" and an arbitrary vector {x,y,z} to be rotated in the direction {0,0,1}.

Comment: I tried to represent the rotation matrices in terms of Cartesian coordinates of the 2nd and 3rd particles, but the expression doesn't agree... (but this may be because my expression is wrong). One thing I noticed is that in your final rotation matrix about z-axis, the sign of the diagonal elements is different between (1,1) and (2,2), which might be wrong if it represents rotation about z.

Comment: Don't worry about it..I will take ur code..thanks again for the help.. I am now working on generating a uniform mesh on a hypersphere in n-dimension.. have you tried something like that before?

Comment: Hmm, no, sorry...(for random points, this [method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Uniformly_at_random_from_the_.28n.C2.A0.E2.88.92.C2.A01.29-sphere) may be useful though). I think  http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ will be the best to ask that question :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about extending it to the nth point but for the 1st 3 going by your ordering:

`new p1 = (0,0,0)` - given

`new p2 = (0,0,dist(p1,p2))`

`new p3 = (0,sin(A)*dist(p1,p3),cos(A)*dist(p1,p3))`

where `A` is the angle between the sides `p1-p3` and `p1-p2` which can be found using law of cosines (since you have the length in between all 3 points):

`A = 
arccos((dist(1,3)*dist(1,3)+dist(1,2)*dist(1,2)-dist(2,3)*dist(2,3))/ (2*dist(1,3)*dist(1,2)))`

Comment: What about the rest of the matrix? I am looking for a rotational matrix A (I believe it should be 3 X 3)  such that A Pos^T = a matrix of size 3 X n = B and the first three rows of B^T has the properties that I want plus the distance between any two rows (particles) is the same as before rotations.

Comment: You're correct 3x3 and with 4 zeros, a single 1. And some +/-sine and cosine. This is if you are doing a roll pitch yaw sort of rotation, so you need to know the roll, pitch and yaw which maybe what @Bobas_Petot was explaining earlier...

Answer (score 0):

Looks my origional answer was deleted... consider changing your code to:

```
! Translating the whole system so that the first particle at the origin
TransX =  pos(1,1)
TransY =  pos(1,2)
TransZ =  pos(1,3)
IF(pos(1,1) .NE. 0.0d0) THEN
  pos(:,1) = pos(:,1) - TransX
END IF  
IF(pos(1,2) .NE. 0.0d0) THEN
  pos(:,2) = pos(:,2) - TransY
END IF
IF(pos(1,3) .NE. 0.0d0) THEN
  pos(:,3) = pos(:,3) - TransZ
END IF
```

Comment: There is no reason why that would change anything. The original code is more readable.

Comment: It is more readable, so the only reason would be if pos(1:1) gets set to zero, and then the rest of the pos(:,1) get set to pos(:,1) - 0... If one was doing this in a DO loop it would work that way, and it should not vectorise as there is a read after write (RaW).  I suppose one could start at pos(2:,1) and do the remaining pos(1,1) post facto. Or what am I missing?

Comment: You are missing that there is no wrong overwriting happenning. The original code in the question is correct. What a DO loop would do is irrelevant here.

Comment: In array expressions the right side is fully evaluated before the assignment to the left hand side.

Comment: Maybe you are right? But he said that the distances all changed after translation!